# Angular: Setting APP_BASE_HREF by environment has no effect

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my Angular App I want to use environments to set the `<base href="">` automatically.

I have the following relevant lines in my `app.module.ts`:

```
...
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from "@angular/common";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
...

...
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.baseHref },
    ...
  ]
...
```

Here are my environment-files:

`environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  ...,
  baseHref: "/app/"
};
```

`environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  ...
  baseHref: "/"
};
```

However, when using `ng build` or `ng build --prod`, neither of the two configuration is applied to the resulting `index.html`.

My Configuration:

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- Angular v4.2.4
- Angular CLI v1.1.1

Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the [`APP_BASE_HREF`](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) is only used with the [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy), it does not alter the `index.html` base href. You should use the command line option for that `--base-href`:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /
```

From the guide:

> Some developers may not be able to add the  element, perhaps because they don't have access to  or the index.html.
>
> Those developers may still use HTML5 URLs by taking two remedial steps:
>
> - Provide the router with an appropriate APP_BASE_HREF value.
> - Use root URLs for all web resources: CSS, images, scripts, and template HTML files.

Comment: From [this guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#html5-urls-and-the--base-href) I understood that I could set it that way instaed of hard-coding the base-href in my index.html. I wanted to avoid using the --base-href option every time

Comment: I've updated my answer. Like the guide states, the `APP_BASE_HREF` only provides the base href for the router, and you should place all resources in the root url `/`. With the `--base-href` build option, the cli replaces the base href in your `index.html` with whatever you provide there. So no need to hardcode

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean, thanks for the update.
But isn't there some official way to include the base-href into index.html from my environment?

Comment: Yes, with the Angular CLI. :-)

Comment: @EnzoVolkmann No, the environment variables are only used to conditionally compile typescript (not completely accurate, but they try to emulate it). They have no effect on any other files. The best way is to use the angular-cli `--base-href`.

Comment: Okay, then I will stick to that solution for now! Thanks for your time, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ng build --prod --base-href <path>`?

see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1064

Comment: Yes, and it works correctly that way. But that is what I wanted to avoid by just setting it once in the environment

Comment: @EnzoVolkmann I know this is a super old question, but couldn't you just add it to your package.json in the `scripts` section and then you wouldn't need to type the command over and over again?